# Has "Error 404" acquired a meaning in everyday English?

Tags: slang

So, we've all seen the web page message "Error 404: Not found."

Apparently, this has now been extended to non-http contexts, and *404* now means a stupid person. Is this true?

Comment: Uh, I think you totally missed the point of my edit.

Comment: I think so too. And I think maybe I missed your point just because you _might_ have missed mine's :):)

Comment: Dont forget Error 418, [I'm a teapot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper_Text_Coffee_Pot_Control_Protocol)

Comment: @Thursagen: Martha's edit was a great improvement, you should revert to that version and make note of how it makes this a much more appropriate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are, currently, 37 entries at urban dictionary for term [404](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=404). They are quite interesting and more than a few of them mention this sense of *stupid, crazy, clueless, useless*.

Answer (score 19):

HTTP Error 404 is a special computer code that indicates that the file you were looking for couldn't be found—in other words, the file's not there as far as the computer is concerned. There could be many reasons why: the file could have been deleted, the link you clicked might have been typoed, or one of a myriad of other reasons.

It generally does not have anything to do with the user—it's just a code that computers use, and by tradition, this code is also displayed to users so they know what happened.

However, according to a [BBC article](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/technology/7775013.stm), the term *404* by itself means *clueless*. This being the BBC, I have no doubt as to the reliability, but it does seem to be local to the UK. This slang would be derived from the computer error, and not the other way around, i.e. the computer is not calling you stupid.

Comment: I've heard "404" used in that same way: "Dude, that guy is 404." I see that the massively descriptivist [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=404) has that meaning listed.

Comment: It is a small step from *not there* to *[not all there](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/not_all_there)*

Comment: Similar to the AE use of "the 411" to mean information - 411 is the phone number for directory enquiries - called "information" in the USA

Comment: I'm sorry, but the answer to your question can not be found. And I'm amazed nobody else has posted [a link to this site](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/60-really-cool-and-creative-error-404-pages/).

Comment: The link is http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/404

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: @NeilFein: If some dude is 404 it means he's "missing something upstairs." :)